# How to get deployment slot in runtime for node.js in azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to get the deployment slot in runtime.
For example I think of something like :

```
process.env.ENVIRONMENT
```

Is there a way to get that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `NODE_ENV` to `development` variable under the Website App settings configuration on the portal.
[image]

Additionally, if you are using the [Azure CLI](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) (which you can install via `npm install azure-cli -g`), you can run the following `azure site config add NODE_ENV=development` assuming your CLI is configured.

Comment: In this case setting will swap when you'll swap between staging and production , please edit your answer to mark the "Slot setting" so I'll pick it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)